# How to Get Only Number on H1 Using XPath?

Tags: html, xpath

How to get number on H1 Using XPath?
Grab only number ( after chapter )

```
<header>
<h1>Example Chapter 01</h1>
<span class="epx">Kamis, 08 Sep 2022, in <i class="fas fa-book-open"></i> <a href="/manga/isekai-de-onnanoko-no-onaneta/" title="Example"> Example</a></span>
</header>
<div class="desch">Example.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please give details of the platform you are using, including what version of XPath is supported.

Answer (score 0):

If your XPath processor supports XPath 2.0, you can use tokenize() to parse the `h1` text by space and then take the last token.  This assumes the number always appears last in the `h1` text preceded by a space.

```
//header/h1/tokenize(., ' ')[last()]
```

returns

```
01
```

With XPath 1.0 you may need to resort to something like using translate() to remove all alphabetic and space characters, but this may not always work depending on the exact content of your chapter titles, e.g.

```
//header/h1/translate(., 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', '')
```

which also returns

```
01
```